# Snowflake - Date format conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake,  I am unable to convert my column to date format. When I try casting, the date column is not correct.

Can anyone help me to convert the particular column in to a date field?

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
            THEN TO_CHAR(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
        ELSE
            TO_CHAR(date1,'MM/DD/YYYY')
    END AS CALL_DATE
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a value you are attempting to convert? It is unclear if the value you are attempting to cast is a date, string (or combination of both)

Comment: I also dont know the out put. i am just converting a oracle querry here. the oracle query is also the same. but need to write this in snowflake.

Comment: What happens when you query `SELECT date1 FROM table LIMIT 2`?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect 2 identical expressions not equal each other: TO_CHAR(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') ?

Comment: no. the date1 column contains null values also another string values. thats y

Comment: @NickW it's the two date values don't match when they are `NULL`, thus is CASE is a very poorly written COALESCE, and they are null when TO_DATE fails to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Coalesce(
        try_to_date(date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
        try_to_date(date1, ‘MM/DD/YYYY’)) as call_date
```

Under snowflake to_date errors if it fails to parse. Thus we should use the TRY_ version.

I do not know exactly when Oracle TO_DATE will return null, but if it does the first branch of the CASE will fall through to the ELSE branch as `NULL = NULL` is `FALSE`.

The original code probably should have been done with a COALESCE or  NVL, as it more clear why you move alone the value chain. Unless Oracles COALESCE evaluates all values at the same time??